# URL Hack, Prepopulate a Lookup Field from Another Lookup Field

Tags: lookup, urlhacking, url

I have ran into a unique issue here. I have Object A which contains a URL button that pre-populates a custom lookup field on Object B. However, I have a URL button on Object B that must pre-populate a custom lookup field on Object C.

The lookup field on Object C needs to be whatever the lookup field on Object B is.

How do I populate the custom lookup field on Object C with the required Name and ID of a record from the custom lookup field on Object B.

Example of the nonfunctional URL.

```
&CF00Na000000B7vs7_lkid={!ObjectB.Lookupfield__c.Id}&CF00Na000000B7vs7={!ObjectB.Lookupfield__c.Name}
```

Comment: When you click the button what is the resulting URL?

Comment: I cannot save the URL logic, gives me an error stating: Field ObjectB.Lookupfield__c.Id does not exist. :(

Comment: When you are creating the button and looking through the merge fields do you see LookupfieldId__c and a Lookupfield__c? If yes, try those, havent' tried it myself but thinking it might work.

Comment: Totally worked! I completely overlooked the insert merge field stuff, thanks again! Post it as an answer so I can mark it as one please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating the button and looking through the merge fields do you see LookupfieldId__c and a Lookupfield__c? If yes, try those.

Answer (score 0):

Just create formula field that will have lookup field reference. Now refer formula field like below -

YourLookupField__c={!URLENCODE(SObjectApiName.YourFormulaeField__c)}